# Image on Surface of a .obj File Unity

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, texture-mapping, .obj

I'm new to Unity and I want to develop a small racing Game. I started to draw the basic parts of the track in an external 3D tool. I saved my designed parts as an .obj file and imported them into unity. An example looks like this.
[What the .obj looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1X6c.png)

The curve had 3 parts, both walls and the ground between those, the ground is a surface object(comes from the .obj file). Now I tried to get something like this:
[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LSKK.png)

But the only way to achieve this optic was to make a new GameObject->Image and set it just above the Ground, there must be an easier way of getting this optic without an extra image. I defined a material out of an image showing asphalt and put it over the surface but the surface just got darker(seems like the average color inside the picture) and didn't show the material.

When I put in a GameObject->Plane and drop the same material onto the plane it looks just like the picture which is perfect, but why isn't it working on my surface out of my .obj file. Can you please show me the correct way to get this done.

Comment: have you uv-unwrapped your model?

Comment: No I didn't.
I will have to research for uv-unwrapping because I don't know that that is. But thanks for the hint now I can do better research.